# XML validation error message always display

Tags: java, xml, struts

I am a Java developer. I'm working with a legacy system which is using Strtus1.2.9. After I added some jar file to this system and started the Tomcat, some error message display in the console. It seems like some of old xml file can not pass the parse. The tracback is like the following:

```
ERROR - Digester.error(1463) | Parse Error at line 396 column 35: Element type "var-value" must be declared.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element type "var-value" must be declared.
    at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLParser.reportError(XMLParser.java:1213)
    at org.apache.xerces.validators.common.XMLValidator.reportRecoverableXMLError(XMLValidator.java:1807)
    at org.apache.xerces.validators.common.XMLValidator.validateElementAndAttributes(XMLValidator.java:3633)
    at org.apache.xerces.validators.common.XMLValidator.callStartElement(XMLValidator.java:1229)
    at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLDocumentScanner$ContentDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentScanner.java:1171)
    at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLDocumentScanner.parseSome(XMLDocumentScanner.java:381)
    at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:1098)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1591)
    at org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorResources.<init>(ValidatorResources.java:159)
    at org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn.initResources(ValidatorPlugIn.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn.init(ValidatorPlugIn.java:162)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:869)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:336)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
```

It seems like some xml has DTD version compatible issue. Why this error never display before. I just add these new jar files:

antlr-runtime-3.1.3.jar
drools-api-5.1.0.jar
drools-compiler-5.1.0.jar
drools-core-5.1.0.jar
drools-decisiontables-5.1.0.jar
drools-templates-5.1.0.jar
flatworm-2.0.1.jar
freemarker.jar
jxl-2.6.10.jar
jxls-reader-0.9.6.jar
mvel2-2.0.16.jar
xml-apis.jar

Comment: You need to edit your post and include the XML file containing the `var-value` tag.

Comment: Jim seems to have it right.  Sounds like the XML doesn't meet the DTD's validation.  Post XML/DTD.

Comment: You've somehow made a change to your system that causes it to do DTD validation when it wasn't doing it before. Can't see why. You could either look at why the XML is invalid and fix it, or you could pursue why it's being validated and prevent it. Doing either needs a lot more information than you've given us.